# Problema con ciclo for android

Tags: java, android

estoy probando una secuencia de código en la que tengo problema, una vez que quiero aprieto el botón en el emulador, se cierra la aplicación. Lo he probado solo en lenguaje JAVA, cambiando la ejecución del textview por un Println y funciona correctamente. Desde ya gracias

```
`    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nombre1 = editText1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "").trim();
            String nombre2 = editText2.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "").trim();

            int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < nombre1.length(); i++) {
                char ch = nombre1.charAt(i);
                int ascii1 = ch;
                sum1 = sum1 + ascii1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nombre2.length(); i++) {
                char ch = nombre2.charAt(i);
                int ascii2 = ch;
                sum2 = sum2 + ascii2;
            }
            int total = sum1 + sum2;

            textView1.setText(total);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Por favor no coloques *resuelta* al título de tu pregunta, con aceptar la respuesta alcanza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que esta sucediendo es que al realizar `textView1.setText(total);` trata de buscar un recurso definido por un id, el método [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) también puede aceptar un id de recurso como parámetro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes cambiar a esta forma convirtiendo el valor de la variable `total` a `String` para que no intente buscar un recurso en el proyecto y simplemente agregue el texto dentro del `TextView`.

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
textView1.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

O de esta forma

```
textView1.setText("" + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías también cambiar el tipo de dato y guardarlo o hacerlo string con el .ToString

```
        textView1.setText(total.toString);
```

O almacenas en una variable y la poner String :

String Variable = total.toString;

```
        textView1.setText(variable);
```

Comment: Hola Lucas, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. No termina de quedar claro qué es lo que sugieres: ¿qué variable debe cambiar de tipo? ¿dónde iría el `.ToString`? ¿Cómo solucionaría eso el problema expuesto en la pregunta? Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir esa información y completar tu solución. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más recomendaciones (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla).

Comment: total.toString en la variable total como hice referencia dos veces ?